# Bitlbee and Facebook group chats

Tags: irc, facebook

I use Bitlbee's own public server (im.bitlbee.org). I have added my Facebook-account to it, but I've noticed that group chats don't work.

I have few group chats on www.facebook.com, but they won't transfer to the IRC-server. Is it atleast possible to manually add the chats if they won't automatically appear? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that facebook doesn't work very well with bitlbee
<sup>(my own new issue is that facebook kick my bitlbee login, claiming I'm already connect)</sup>

Anyway, I think that is is related to message/chat. In particular, I have contacts that disable chat completely. I can still message them fine (via web site), but no message they send is treated like a chat (and is not sent to bilbee). I believe that "Group Chats" are handled more like a "Group Messages", as they show the same behavior as above.

Comment: Fb works otherwise fine for me, but I don't still know how do I open or join in existing group chat. I'm also open for alternatives to Bitlbee :)

Answer (score 0):

there's now a new module for bitlbee, details are on: https://wiki.bitlbee.org/HowtoFacebookMQTT

With this, using the /fbchat, /fbjoin and /fbcreate commands, you can use Facebook group chats (again).